# Could someone explain how to solve this problem?

Tags: integers

Let  $$f(x)=x^2-3$$
For how many integer values of x is $f(f(f(x)))$ divisible by x?

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, but I know what I would do to try to find a solution. The first thing would be to insert $x=0,1,2,3$ or $4$ and see what pops out. You should try that. And please let us know the results.

Comment: In general, if $h$ is an integer polynomial and $x$ is an integer, then $x$ is a divisor of $h(x)-h(0).$ So $x$ is a divisor of $h(x)$ if and only if $x$ is a divisor of $h(0).$

Comment: Could you give me more hints? do you mean I should solve for h(0)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$f(f(x))=(x^2-3)^2-3$$ and now what is $$f(f(f(x))$$?

Comment: The f(f(f(x)) becomes very complicated, I don't know the next step to solve this problem